# Is there a way to display a chart label that has no data behind it in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I m trying to display an anual unemployment statistic on chart.js but I don't have the data for all the months. Is it possible to display all the data I have but keep all the labels( like for example I dont have data for july, I want the label 'july' to be written down there but no dot in the chart).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should define the `xAxis` as a [time cartesian axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html). Then you define the `data` of your dataset as [individual points](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#point) through objects containing `x` and `y` properties.

> Please note that Chart.js internally uses [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) for the functionality of the time axis. Therefore you should use the [bundled version](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/installation.html#bundled-build) of Chart.js that includes Moment.js in a single file.

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart"), {
  type: "line",
  data: {   
    datasets: [{
      label: "Unemployments",
      data: [
        { x: '2020-01', y: 50 },
        { x: '2020-02', y: 55 },
        { x: '2020-03', y: 67 },
        { x: '2020-04', y: 40 },
        { x: '2020-05', y: 20 },
        { x: '2020-07', y: 35 },
        { x: '2020-08', y: 38 },
        { x: '2020-09', y: 45 },
        { x: '2020-10', y: 48 },
        { x: '2020-11', y: 52 },
        { x: '2020-12', y: 55 }
      ],
      backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
      borderColor: 'blue',
      pointRadius: 5,
      pointHoverRadius: 10,
      fill: false,
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }        
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',               
        time: {
          unit: 'month',
          parser: 'YYYY-MM',
          displayFormats: {
            month: 'MMMM'
          },
          tooltipFormat: 'MMMM'
        }
      }]
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="90"></canvas>
```